# In IE8 how to use a Telerik grid with the YUI3 grids without any overlapping?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, telerik, yui

I am using the latest version of the `Yahoo User Interface 3 (YUI)`.  I am using the `reset, fonts, grids and base stylesheets`.  I am also using the latest version of the `Telerik MVC extensions`.  I am doing my website in `ASP.NET MVC 3` using the `razor view engine`.  Browser is `Internet Explorer 8`.

I am have an issue with my layout and not sure what is causing it.  I have a header and footer section, and the content part consists of a right and a left column.

Here are my stylesheers that I am using:

```
<link type="text/css" href="/Content/2011.3.1115/telerik.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link type="text/css" href="/Content/2011.3.1115/telerik.webblue.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link type="text/css" href="/Content/cssreset-min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link type="text/css" href="/Content/cssfonts-min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link type="text/css" href="/Content/cssgrids-min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link type="text/css" href="/Content/cssbase-min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link type="text/css" href="/Content/mystylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

I have just some basic markup added to my view (the colours are there for display purposes only):

```
<div id="hd" style="background-color:Aqua;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Maecenas sit amet metus. Nunc quam elit, posuere nec, auctor in, rhoncus quis, dui. Aliquam erat volutpat. Ut dignissim, massa sit amet dignissim cursus, quam lacus feugiat.</div>
<div class="yui3-g">
     <div class="yui3-u" id="nav" style="background-color:Yellow;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Maecenas sit amet metus. Nunc quam elit, posuere nec, auctor in, rhoncus quis, dui. Aliquam erat volutpat. Ut dignissim, massa sit amet dignissim cursus, quam lacus feugiat.</div>
     <div class="yui3-u" id="main" style="background-color:Lime;">

          @(Html.Telerik()
               .Grid<GrantApplicationListViewModel>()
               .Name("grdGrantApplications")
               .Columns(column =>
               {
                    column.Bound(x => x.Id)
                         .Title("Ref #");
               })
               .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax().Select("AjaxGrantApplicationsBinding", "Home"))
               .Pageable(paging => paging.PageSize(20))
          )

     </div>
</div>
<div id="ft" style="background-color:Aqua;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Maecenas sit amet metus. Nunc quam elit, posuere nec, auctor in, rhoncus quis, dui. Aliquam erat volutpat. Ut dignissim, massa sit amet dignissim cursus, quam lacus feugiat.</div>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
@(Html.Telerik()
     .ScriptRegistrar()
     .jQuery(false)
)
```

The grid loads with 10 records.  After it has loaded it overlaps my footer.  I checked it in IE9 and it looks fine, the footer is below the grid.  But in IE8 the grid goes over the footer.  How would I get this to display correctly in IE8?  Is there a bug in IE8 when it displays markup?

**UPDATE:**

This is all that I have in my stylesheet.  The rest is in the above mentioned stylesheets.  It's a very basic layout.  My original layout is like above but it had other styles as well, so I stripped it of everything to make sure that it is not my styles that is causing this issue.

```
body{margin:auto;width:1000px;}
#nav{width:250px;}
#main{width:750px;}
```

Comment: You have posted here the structure. But to solve you problem we also need to know some CSS that your page is using.

Comment: Nobody here that can help me?  I'm assuming it's a CSS issue, I'm not that clued up on CSS.  It's really a basic implementation that I have here.  Just copy and paste and it should work.

Comment: When testing in IE 8 is the browser in 'Standards' document mode? I have tested your page with a simplified Telerik grid, but without a DocType at the top of my Razor view IE 8 (and 9) use document mode 'Quirks'. In that case I don't get any overlap but the whole page is aligned to the left and the footer of the grid gets mixed up. When I add the following DocType at the top of my view, the page is displayed normally:
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post the rendered output. Not everyone has access to .Net. ;) Maybe a link to an example page?

Comment: Hi there, I'm not sure how much this comment will help but certainly is not an answer at all... Have you tried to review your div/classes structure following the pattern suggested on http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/cssgrids/cssgrids-fixed.html?

Comment: Can you make this behave the way you're describing in the OP: http://jsfiddle.net/vjTve/ - then you'll get an answer for sure.

Comment: use Firebug and experiment with it

Comment: is this happening on the t-grid-pager CSS class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a front-end developer, might I suggest NEVER using Telerik.  It is actually quite terrible from an HTML/CSS standpoint.  It's basically the asp.net equivalent of using Dreamweaver hooks.

Letting microsoft automatically generate markup/css/js and imagining it will be flexible enough to play nice with other libraries might be a bit of a pipe-dream, in 90% of the cases I've experienced you're better off not using it (sorry to be mr. negative, I've got a lot of experience untangling telerik issues - and most of the time there is no quick or simple answer).

Comment: I have to use it, work standards.  If I use YUI grids, it does the same thing.

Comment: One thing YUI grids does not do is generate markup like this:

 <input type="hidden"        name="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderMain_UserInformation_userControl_tbFirstName_ClientState"        id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderMain_UserInformation_userControl_tbFirstName_ClientState"
        autocomplete="off">

TERRIBLE!